# Error when using '/' operator with sphere material attribute and a float (glsl)

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, webgl, fragment-shader

I'm implementing simple ray tracing for spheres in a fragment shader. At this point, I'm currently working on the function that computes color for a diffusely shaded sphere. The issue I'm having is that I'm trying to calculate the Normal vector from a surface point using the equation: N = (S - sph.xyz) / sph.r
However, when I try to translate this to glsl,I'm getting the error that those operands can't be used with the '/' operator (i.e.

```
ERROR: 0:37: '/' :  wrong operand types  no operation '/' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'in mediump 3-component vector of float' and a right operand of type 'const int' (or there is no acceptable conversion) )
```

In addition to fixing this apparent error, I'm not really sure even how to go about structuring this function to diffusely shade the sphere being rendered so any guidance on that would be greatly appreciated. The code for the function is below (and probably ridden with errors):

```
vec3 shadeSphere(vec3 point, vec4 sphere, vec3 material) {
      vec3 color = vec3(1.,2.,3.);
      vec3 N = (point - sphere.xyz) / sphere.w;
      float diffuse = max(dot(Ldir, N), 0.0);
      float ambient = material/5;
      color = ambient   + Lrgb * diffuse *  max(0, N * Ldir);
      return color;
   }
```

Comment: The error message says *exactly* what's wrong. `no operation '/' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'in mediump 3-component vector of float' and a right operand of type 'const int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`  It says right in the error there is no '/' that can work with a vec3 on left and an int on the right.

Comment: @gman The answer provided actually solved the problem, I just changed the name of the post in order to make it so that people with the same issue can find it more easily.

Comment: Yes it did. I'm just pointing out if you had actually read the error message you might have figured it out. There was nothing ambiguous about that message. `material` is a `3-component vector or float` and `5` is a `const int`. the error message says you can't do that. your post makes it seem like you didn't read the message and just barfed a question out on stack overflow. I'm not saying that's what happened. maybe you didn't understand the error message. But, the error message was actually the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the error is your `material/5`. You are dividing a vector by an integer and assigning it to a float. You probably want `vec3 ambient = material/5.0;` for proper types and calculations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seemed to fix that error! There was a second part of the question that I had in the post. I just put it in a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32743068/how-to-structure-function-to-diffusely-shade-sphere), do you think you might be able to help?